# Asynchronous Node, Mongoose Inserting in Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I have a CSV file that I am reading in with hundreds of lines. Based of a row in the CSV file I am creating a 'project' and storing it into my projects collection. Each project has a Category as well which is its own Model. So many projects can have the same Category. Both collections start of with nothing and I need to populate both these collections based of the CSV file. The issue I am having is that since many rows contain the same category, often right after another, multiple category documents of the same type are created since everything is happening asynchronously. I have code like this:

```
    exports.upload = function(req, res) {
var reader = csv.createCsvFileReader("test.csv", {columnsFromHeader:true, nestedQuotes:true});
reader.addListener('data', function(data) {        
    projectService.findCategory(data.Category, function(id){
        var Project = mongoose.model('Project');
        var project = new Project();
        project.name = data.Name;
        project.narrative = data.Narrative;
        project.address = data.address;
        project.category = id;
        project.lat = data.Lat;
        project.lng = data.Lng;
        project.save(function(err){
            console.log(project);
            if(err){
                console.log("There was an error in saving your project");
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

}

and

```
    exports.findCategory = function(projectCategory, callback) {
var Category = mongoose.model('Category');
Category.findOne({ name: projectCategory }, function(err, categoryReturned){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Could not return a category");
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    if(categoryReturned == null){ //If category does not exist create a new category. 
        category = new Category({name : projectCategory});
        console.log(category);
        category.save(function(err, categoryCreated){
            console.log('New Category Created');
            callback(categoryCreated._id);
        });
    }else{
        callback(categoryReturned._id);
    }
});
```

}

Here is some sample input:

```
    "Name","Narrative","Address","Category","Lat","Lng","Year_Completed","Sponsors"
    "Raymond Avenue Neighborhood Garden Construction","","","3",34.0317141377768,-118.297777175903,"2010","??? (City of Los Angeles, The Garden Council)"
    "El Cariso Smart Garden Construction","","","3",34.3169450092985,-118.419291973114,"2010","L.A. County Parks and Recreation"
    "Central Basin Friendly Native Plants Garden","","","2",33.9955722580013,-118.144440650939,"2010","Central Basin Municipal Water District"
```

This creates two '3' Category entries. I know why. I dont know how to get around it.

Comment: Before saving the project, your code moves to next iteration or next line of CSV. There you check whether category already exists or not. It's possible that it might or might not exist, depending on whether project is already saved. There are 2 solutions

1. Make the whole operation slow by moving to next operation after saving.
2. Use aggregate once all the inserts are completed.

Comment: @nightgaunt how do i wait for something to save before moving to the next operation. i though since node is asynch i cant do that?? thanks any advice will help.

Comment: Recursion!! That's the savior in this kind of situation. Let me know if you want me to write the code block in an answer. Since I don't know how `createCsvFileReader`, I will explain it with a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataArray = new Array(YOUR DATA);
var index = 0;
(function(data) {
    var presentFunction = argument.callee;
    projectService.findCategory(data.Category, function(id){
        var Project = mongoose.model('Project');
        var project = new Project();
        project.name = data.Name;
        project.narrative = data.Narrative;
        project.address = data.address;
        project.category = id;
        project.lat = data.Lat;
        project.lng = data.Lng;
        project.save(function(err){
           console.log(project);
           if(err){
               console.log("There was an error in saving your project");
            console.log(err);
            return;
           }
           if (index > dataArray.length - 1) {
               return;
           } else {
               index++;
               presentFunction(dataArray[index]);
           }
        });
    });
})(dataArray[index]);
```

This ought to do it. The solution is crude with a lot of scope for improvement, but you get the idea.